# divide field input by 12 using Javascript

Tags: javascript, input, divide

I need to take the number that the user is keying into an input field and display underneath the field what this number would be divided by 12. This needs to be pure JS, not Jquery.

ideally it needs to be rounded off also, so 1083.3333333333333 would become 1083

Thanks

Comment: what you have tried??? any effort from your side ?

Comment: Math.round(2.5); http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_round.asp try this may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
var userInput = document.getElementById('number');
userInput.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if (isNumeric(this.value) == true) {
      var divide = Math.round(this.value / 12);
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = divide;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'please enter number';
    }
})

function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number">
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: is it possible to do this without the submit button? i just need it to work as the user is typing. thanks for your reply

Comment: Yeah it is possible.

Comment: Now check out this

Comment: Instead of using the setTimeout you can better add the event to `keyup`. Bit more intuitive

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @PhillipClarke replace keydown event to keyup as well as remove the setTimeout function.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it feels like doing someone else's homework. Anyways, this will probably help you along the way. Even though this is very basic javascript and html, which you could have easily looked up online or in your course book :)

*spoiler: untested code ahead*

**html**

```
<input id="number" type="text">
<div id="output"></div>
```

**js**

```
//obtain reference to number html element
var number = document.getElementById('number');

//obtain reference to output html element
var output = document.getElementById('output');

//what you want to divide to
var division = 12; // can't be 0, or the world will explode

//add an eventlistener to the change event on the number element
number.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {

  //get the value from the input
  var val = parseFloat(number.value);

  //check if it is a nan
  if(!isNaN(val)) {

     //round it to 0 digits
     output.innerHTML = (val / division).toFixed(0) + "";
  } else {
     output.innerHTML = 'that\'s not a number!';
  }
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q2eLyxz9/)

Comment: I'm fairly certain 90% of this hasn't been covered by the teacher yet. 100% if they're just learning basic operations and math functions. ;) So you gave him the answer, correctly, but it's not an answer he can use. Hehe.

Comment: @PhillipClarke Woops.. i am sorry.. been too busy with angular2. `innerHTML` vs `innerHtml`. I've updated my answer, and changed the event to `keyup` instead of change. [https://jsfiddle.net/q2eLyxz9/](https://jsfiddle.net/q2eLyxz9/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updatesum()
 {
        document.input.total.value = Math.ceil(document.input.input1.value / 80) * Math.ceil(document.input.input2.value / 80) * Math.ceil(document.input.input3.value / 80);
        return false;
    }
</script>
<body>
    <form name="input" action="#" method="get" onsubmit="return false;">
        Calculator<br>
        Value1:<input type="text" name="input1" value=""><br>
        Value2:<input type="text" name="input2" value="2"><br>
        Value3:<input type="text" name="input3" value=""><br>
        Costs:<input type="text" name="total" value="">
        <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="updatesum()">
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```